# Question about feeding a group of cylinders into a tube

Tags: design

I'm currently trying to design a mechanism that can feed a bottle of capsules into a tube. However, I've stumbled across the problem where as the capsule is a cylinder, any tube opening will allow for the capsule to either enter on its side or upright.

Is there a way to make it such that I can feed the capsules into the tube lying down? I tried to search up a vending machine dispenser like mechanism but I couldn't find any results.

Comment: `any tube opening will allow for the capsule to either enter on its side or upright.` ... how many openings are there in the tube? ... it is unclear what you are trying to do ... please draw a diagram,  if possible

Comment: At the top is a funnel which is connected to a kind of test-tube like structure. I want the pills to be loaded into the test-tube after being dumped into the funnel. I'm not too sure how I can orient the pills such that they all enter the test-tube on their side instead of vertically.

Comment: the answer to an `is there a way?` question is almost always a `yes, there is a way` ... try to find out how *PEZ* candies are packaged

Comment: Pill counter: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Fat.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYRTj.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Consider to view [Mellow_labs video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZQ9VuxIBHU) (or the entire sequence) to see how he designed and 3D printed a set of dispenser modules to provide controlled movement of different pill shapes.

The design involves a stepper motor rotating a custom printed disk with a hole shaped specifically for the target capsule. The capsule may not be engaged immediately, but when it is collected, it is dropped into the chute for delivery.

An extension from this is to use this design and mechanism to load the cylinder into a tube which will then orient it to your requirements.